# Reload a part of the WordPress page with jquery or similar to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

hi  i am  a new programer I want to update part of my wordpress page content which is a shortcode from a php file without refreshing the whole page.
But I don't know how to use hook and action in the **function.php** file of the child theme and also how to write the **abc.js** file with jquery and ajax

my php file for shortcode is SetP.php

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();
$postname="$current_user->user_login";
$result=$wpdb->get_results("select Set_P_Ref from mainlogs where Srl_Pro='$postname'");
echo "<style>";
    echo ".tt {
        color:white;
  font-weight: normal;
font-family: refled;
     }";

echo "</style>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<div class=\"table\"><table>";
foreach($result as $row){
    echo "<tr><td class=tt >" .$row->Set_P_Ref ."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table></div>";
```

This program is active, but due to the fact that my output parameter is changed, this value is not updated except by refreshing the whole page.

I will be very grateful for your help

plz

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking for an entire AJAX solution is a bit too broad of a question for SO. I would highly recommend reading this: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/ it's more than 10 years old, but the information is still very relevant.

Comment: Ignoring AJAX, does this even work? Where is `$Set_P_Ref` defined? I had to lookup [`settype`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php), and except for some very special cases, I feel like it should be avoided. `echo "</head>"` seems dubious. What is it closing? `get_currentuserinfo` is [deprecated](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_currentuserinfo/). You are asking for an SQL injection, use [`wpdb::prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)

Comment: Yes, it works by ignoring ajax, I just have to keep refreshing the whole page to see the output changes  , get_currentuserinfo is deprecated, but it still works for me, so I didn't replace it with its new function and settype was unnecessary and redundant, I edited the program

Comment: Thanks for addressing most of those issues. Have you tried writing any [AJAX code from the codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/enqueuing/)?

Comment: I am new to ajax and I would be grateful if you could help me

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [sql injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), you should use [wpdb->prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) to sanitize your queries.

Answer (score 1):

*A new programmer*: Welcome to our great trade! With respect you've chosen a fairly elaborate first WordPress project. Explaining it all is far beyond the scope of a WordPress answer.

Here's the outline of a solution to your problem, hopefully to point you in some useful directions.

1. Write a [plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) to ...
2. implement a [shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/) or [custom block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/create-block/) to write out some simple HTML to show that automatically updated information in an HTML element with an id, something like

   ```html
   <div id='saras-plugin'>whatever information</div>
   ```
3. In the plugin, implement a [custom REST API endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/) that returns the updated information you need.
4. Write the Javascript you need to put into the page, to hit the custom REST API from the browser and get the information. You can use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or the newer and better [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to do this. Then your Javascript will use [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to find the html you wrote out in step 2, and change its contents to hold your new information.
5. In your shortcode or custom block handler call [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to tell WordPress to put your Javascript code into the page.
6. Put the shortcode or block you just created into the content of your website where you want the dynamic information displayed.

A lot of programming steps, sure. But when you master this stuff you'll have some super valuable skills.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to write this. It is very disheartening when I see new programmers being told to RTFM or "scrap everything and start over" or similar, so seeing someone actually try to help, even though the task is more complicated than the person thought, it very wonderful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I am just starting out and I enjoy meeting experienced professionals like you who give helpful and compassionate guidance. All the parts of the project were simple and I did them, except for this part, I do not have